# Codenvy: how to checkout single file or files/dirs using git?

Tags: git, ide, command, cloud, codenvy

I begin to use the one of the cloud IDEs which is Codenvy.

It seems the best one among the cloud IDEs, but I still find something troubles, such as git command.
I want to checkout a single file which I changed wrong when I realized,
but I even cannot find a normal `git checkout` way---even by using shell, the git commands are very limited.

I also have looked through its document about git [here](http://docs.codenvy.com/user/code-management/regular-git-operations/) but nothing found.

Has anybody encountered this problem, please?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout just one file is:

```
git checkout -- path/to/your/file
```

That would reset its content. If Codenvy has a shell allowing git commands, that would be one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you @Vonc, I know git and use it in my daily work;). I just don't know how to use the **checkout** way in the cloud IDE **Codenvy** as it seems not provide full support for git even in its shell, which usage is very limited.

Comment: @tech_me, did you figure out how to do this?